# Edit jquery editable select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I need a little help for this script. It is a [jQuery Plugin](http://indrimuska.github.io/jquery-editable-select/) that converts a select into an text field with suggestions. When I use it in a form it submits the text not the value.

How can I use get the value of options not the text?

Example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https:rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.css">

<form action="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437449/edit-jquery-editable-select/" method="get">
 <select id="basic" name="basic">
  <option value="0">Zero</option>
  <option value="1">One</option> 
  <option value="2">Two</option> 
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
 $('#basic').editableSelect();
}
</script>
```

It should send `"000"` not `"zero"`, and results in `domian.com/page.php?data=000` not `domian.com/page.php?data=zero`.

Comment: Can you edit your post with your code (js, html) ?

Comment: How are you currently getting the value, the way that gives you zero?

Comment: using <form method="get">

Comment: I need to edit "jquery-editable-select.min.js" file

Comment: If you try to submit your form without your jQuery plugin, do you still have your error?

Comment: it works without jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATE:***

Another way in order to get the value you are looking for is:

```
$('#basic').siblings('.es-list').find('li.selected').data('value')
```

For the text instead you can use:

```
$('#basic').siblings('.es-list').find('li.selected').text()
```

***Old answer:***

The plugin [jquery-editable-select](https://github.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select) exposes an event called "onSelect".

So you need to attach an event handler for this event and listen for the form submit:

```js
$(function () {
  var selectedEleValue = null;
  $('#basic').editableSelect({
    onSelect: function (element) {
      selectedEleValue = element.val();
      console.log('The val is: ' + element.val() + ' The text is: ' + element.text());
    }
  });
  $('form[action="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437449/edit-jquery-editable-select/"]').on('submit', function(e) {
    if (selectedEleValue != null) {
      $('#basic').val(selectedEleValue);
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://rawgit.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js"></script>

<form action="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437449/edit-jquery-editable-select/" method="get">
    <select id="basic" name="basic">
        <option value="0">Zero</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: @Ahmed Could you try my snippet?

Comment: if 2 select in jsp  .siblings('.es-list').find('li.selected').data('value') return same result or undifined, why? how handle it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>


  <script  src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <link href="./jquery-editable-select-master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="./jquery-editable-select-master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {

      $('#basic').editableSelect();

    });


    function abc(){

        var basic_text = document.getElementById('basic').value;

        var basic_value = $('#basic').siblings('.es-list').find('li.selected').attr('value');


        console.log(basic_text);

        console.log(basic_value);

    }


  </script>

</head>
<body>



<form method="post" id="form_id" action="">
    <select id="basic" name="basic">
        <option value="0">Zero</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" onclick="abc();">Submit</button>
</form>



</body>
</html>
```