# Set value of jQuery Editable Select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the [jQuery Editable Select](http://indrimuska.github.io/jquery-editable-select/). What I'm trying to accomplish is to clear the filtered text after selection.

And Here is my sample code: (similar available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xfmuoqn6/2/))

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https:rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.css">

<form action="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437449/edit-jquery-editable-select/" method="get">
    <select id="basic" name="basic">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">Opt1</option>
        <option value="2">Opt2</option> 
        <option value="3">Opt3</option> 
    </select>
</form>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#basic')
    .editableSelect()
    .on('select.editable-select', function (e, li) {
       if (!li) {
           return;
       }
       const oldVal = li.val();

// Do some important stuff... 

// And Here I would like to clear the text and to remove all the filters
  //     $("#basic").val("0")// set the value to default one
   ///   $("#basic").val('') // does not work correcntly. See bellow.
   })
}
</script>
```

**Edit**

**$("#basic").val('');**
Does not work, because this is the result:
[image]

The selected area is empty, but it still uses the old filtered value.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('#basic').val('')` to remove the value of the input field. May it can help you.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Unfortunately this does not work for me:(. I updated the question with the result.

Comment: I know one long solution if you want to try. The solution is you have to search the sibling by using


$('#basic').siblings('ul').children('li').each((index, item) => {
    item.style.display = 'none'
})

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but you can control the select by setting the value of the text field.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#basic')
    .editableSelect()
    .on('select.editable-select', function (e, li) {
       if (!li) {
           return;
       }
       const oldVal = li.val();

       // Do some important stuff... 


       $("#basic").val(''); // set the value of the text field to an empty string.
       
       // Or

       $("#basic").val('Audi'); // set the value of the text field to a specific string.
   })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Unfortunately this does not work for me:(. I updated the question with the result.